# Error: Why 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type even though the pointer is set to an object?

Tags: c++, unions, void-pointers

I have the following code ([live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/696ea1d5bba866d1)):

```
// untouchable extern library .hpp  file

typedef union ExternLibraryUnion
{
    int a;
    float b;
}ExternLibraryUnion;

// my code

#include <iostream>

class Container{
    public:
    Container() : m_union(NULL) {};

    ~Container(){
        if(m_union){
            delete m_union;
        }
    }

    void init(){
        m_union = new ExternLibraryUnion();
    }

    ExternLibraryUnion* get_union(){
        return m_union;
    }

private:
    ExternLibraryUnion* m_union;
};


class Master{
    public:
    Master() : m_union(NULL) {
        m_container.init();    
    };

    ~Master(){
        if(m_union){
            delete static_cast<ExternLibraryUnion*>(m_union);
        }
    }

    void load(){

    }

    void set(int i){
        m_union = m_container.get_union();
        m_union->a = i;
    }

    void* get_union(){
        return m_union;
    }

private:
    void* m_union;
    Container m_container;
};

class Worker{
    public:
    Worker() : m_extern_library_union(NULL) {};

    ~Worker(){
        if (m_extern_library_union){
            delete m_extern_library_union;
        }
    }

    void load(Master& master){
        m_extern_library_union = reinterpret_cast<ExternLibraryUnion*>(master.get_union());
    }

    int get_int(){
        return m_extern_library_union->a;
    }


private:
    ExternLibraryUnion* m_extern_library_union;
};

int main()
{
    Master master;
    master.set(3);

    Worker worker;
    worker.load(master);

    std::cout << worker.get_int() << std::endl;
}
```

The code produces:

```
main.cpp: In member function 'void Master::set(int)':
main.cpp:55:16: error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
         m_union->a = i;
                ^~
```

In an extern library, a `union ExternLibraryUnion` is defined which I'm using inside my own code. My problem, which I can't get my head around, is in the `set` method of class `Master`. The `Master` member `void* m_union` should point to the union stored inside the member `Container m_container`. As I'm setting the `m_union = m_container.get_union()` the compiler should be able to know that I'm getting a `ExternLibraryUnion*` back from the `get_union()` method call. So I don't quite the error arising from the assignment `m_union->a = i`. Sure, a `void*` has no type, but I assigned it a pointer of the precise type `ExternLibraryUnion`.

Let's also say I can not touch the `Container m_container` object directly. I need to make the assigned through the `void* m_union` pointer.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: How would the language know what you've set it to? `void*` is `void*.

Comment: `void*` is used when you don't know what you are pointing to. If you don't know what you are pointing to, how can you assign to a member of it?

Comment: Pro Tip: if you are using `void*` for anything other than interfacing with a legacy or C-style API that forces you to use `void *` you are almost certainly headed down a bad path.

Comment: void* is for the case where you know what it points to but don't want the code or the compiler to know.

Comment: Why are you not using a `ExternLibraryUnion*` in `Master`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler has *no clue* what `m_union` might *actually* be pointing at.  You declared it as a `void *` so the compiler believes you, it has no choice.  And that's *all* it knows, so `m_union->a` has to be flagged as an error, because `->a` has no meaning to the compiler here.

To put it another way, RTTI aside, pointers don't 'know' what they're pointing at.  The compiler only knows how the pointer was *declared*.

I don't know what else to say, it's really that simple.  I don't like having to say this, but looking at the code as a whole, it looks like a complete mess.  Who wrote it?

[Edit] And what Jeffrey said will indeed fix it, but that's not what you asked.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up for me! Now I actually understand the cause of the error. This code was written by a couple of students and I basically stripped down the code to be able to post it here. I was told to be able to do this 'task' of setting the void pointer.

Comment: Note for those that follow: RTTI: [RunTime Type Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information)

Comment: @DummySenior Excellent, that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
private:
void* m_union;
```

to

```
private:
ExternLibraryUnion* m_union;
```

at line 63. As your code stand, you upcast the pointer to void*, and then, at the next line the compiler can't know the pointed type.

If you can't change the type, you can static_cast the void pointer to an 
ExternLibraryUnion*. Then use that to access. Since you know the type, the static_cast could be "acceptable". But not the nicest design by any measure.

Comment: "dynamic_cast will work": not from a `void *`, I believe.  You have to use `static_cast`.

Comment: hahah. right. Never knew that. I guess I didn't use enough void* pointer. Will fix.

Comment: @Jeffrey -- no, you've probably used `void*` too many times. <g> Not understanding it's limitations is not a bad thing: just don't use it.